# Google plus api shut down

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-client

I have seen an update that Google+ APIs will be shut down on March 7, 2019. I am working on a maintenance project which has below two google apis. But I am not sure whether these two calls are google or google plus api. If it is google plus then I have to replace it.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=birthdays

Appreciate your response on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these use the Google+ API. The first is part of the [OAuth and OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode) framework and the second is the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/).

You should be good for both.